# Executing Javascripts in a specific order

Tags: javascript, php, seq

I have three (3) javascripts that I am trying to execute in a specific order.  My problem is that each javascript uses data set by the previous script.  My first script, which executes on loading, gets data from an SQL database and copies it to the body of my web page.  The next javascript needs some of this data to execute properly  In order to execute the second script, I must wait not only until the previous script has completed execution but until the data has been loaded to the body of my web page so that it can be accessed by the second script.  The relationship between the second and third scripts is similar.  I've not been able to find any previous question and answer that addresses the use of data extracted by a previous script.  Any help that you can offer will be very much appreciated.  Here's an example of my latest attempt.

```
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById("inputCounter").innerHTML = 1;
    var recordCounter = document.getElementById("inputCounter");
    var number = recordCounter.innerHTML;
    querySQL(number);
    document.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (document.readystate == "complete")
        {
            getIPDetail('https://freegeoip.net/csv/');
        }
    };
}
```

myFunction() executes on loading of the page body.  The first script called from myFuntion() is querySQL(number).  The second script called from myFunction() is getIPDetail('https://freegeoip/csv/').  My problem is that detIPDetail... does not execute because it needs data that querySQL inserts into a div on the page body.

Comment: You should be thinking in context of functions not scripts. When you load your browser, if you include them all in your web page at the same time, they all process at the same time. If your pieces of functionality are organized in functions it's simply a matter of calling said function when you need to.

Comment: What do you mean by "my first javascript, my second javascript" ? Are you talking about `<script>`s ?

Comment: You have to paste the implementation of functions querySQL() and getIPDetail() here for us to help you further.

Comment: The possible cause of the problem is getIPDetails() is getting invoked immediately when ajax finishes and momentarily before the callback function (probably defined in querySQL) receives the response and inserts it into hidden div.

An easy way to solve this could be - keep the div blank during initialization. And use the following code in  if(document.readystate=='complete') block:

var intvl = setInternal(function() { 
if(document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML!="") { getIPDetail(); clearInterval(intvl); }
 }, 50);

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem through experimentation.  In other words, I found the right positions in my code to put the javascript function calls so that my application flowed properly.